# Is it possible to migrate docker volume to Cloud Sql?

Tags: postgresql, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a production environment running in google cloud and it is running using docker compose. I have database containers running postgresql and I’ve been searching to see if it is possible to migrate these volumes to Cloud SQL for better management of the dBs, but I haven’t found anything. I’m new at this of cloud management so I don’t have that much of experience to know where to start.

Comment: In short, you can't. Export your data and load them in a new Cloud SQL instance.